# Using [HttpGet] Attribute in ASP.NET MVC action causes download failed in Chrome iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, asp.net-mvc

I have an action in ASP.NET MVC which looks like:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Download() {
   return File( ... );
}
```

and in javascript:

```
...
location.href = '/Home/Download';
```

Seems that in Chrome iOS, the download failed. But in Safari works fine.

If I remove `[HttpGet]` then download works.

What is the problem ? Does it is a bug or something related with `[HttpGet]` attribute ?

Comment: upgrade your chrome, it should work

Comment: It has latest version...

Comment: try leaving off the `.href` part and just use `location = '/Home/Download'`